# Como resolver o erro Uncaught TypeError: hidden is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, funções, button, onclick

Eu tenho um arquivo javascript com esse código:

```
const newTopic = document.getElementById('topic');
const introduction = document.getElementById('introduction');

function hidden(){
    if(introduction.classList.contains("hidde")){
        introduction.classList.add('hidde');
        introduction.classList.remove('discussions-introduction');
        newTopic.classList.remove('hidde');
    }
}
```

e no meu html tem esse botao aqui:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="hidden()">criar tópico</button>
```

mas quando eu vou usar essa funcao ela não funciona, e o console me retorna esse erro:

```
index.html:150 Uncaught TypeError: hidden is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

o javascript esta sendo chamado aqui:

```
<script src="./js/newTopic.js"></script>
```

o que pode estar dando errado?

Answer (score 1):

Altere o nome da `function` pois está ocorrendo um conflito entre o nome da `function hidden`. Pois o `hidden` é um Atributo Global. O mesmo tipo de conflito acontece ao você colocar algo como ***HTML Attributes* (Atributos HTML)**,  ***HTML Global Attributes* (Atributos Globais HTML como o hidden de exemplo)**, ***Global Events Attributes* (Atributos de Eventos Globais)** com o mesmo nome para a `function`. O mesmo tipo de conflito acontece ao você colocar um `id` ou `name` no `button` com o mesmo nome da `function`

- **Atributos HTML** são valores adicionais que configuram os elementos ou
  ajustam seu comportamento de várias maneiras para atender aos
  critérios que os usuários desejam.
- **Atributos Globais** são atributos comuns a todos elementos HTML; Os
  atributos globais são atributos que podem ser usados ​​com todos os
  elementos HTML, embora os atributos não tenham efeito em alguns
  elementos.
- **Atributos de Eventos Globais:** eventos acionem ações em um navegador,
  como iniciar um JavaScript quando um usuário clica em um elemento. *( Mouse Events, Keyboard Events, Form Events, Window Events, etc...)*

E que ao invés de colocar hidden coloque hidde, ou algo que seja melhor para sua identificação.

```js
const newTopic = document.getElementById('topic');
const introduction = document.getElementById('introduction');

function hidde(){
    alert('teste Está funcionando')
    if(introduction.classList.contains("hidde")){
        introduction.classList.add('hidde');
        introduction.classList.remove('discussions-introduction');
        newTopic.classList.remove('hidde');
    }
}
```

```html
<button  id="btn" onclick="hidde()"> </button>
```

Lista de todos atributos que, se caso não funcionar, você confere aí:

- Todos os Atributos HTML:
  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp
- Todos os Atributos Globais HTML:
  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp
- Todos os Atributos de evento HTML:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp